# How to run a .pyc file when it imports some other .py files?

Tags: python, pyc

main.py

```
import other

def main():
   other.test()

main()
```

other.py

```
def test():
   print("Hello")
```

By using `python3 -m py_compile *.py`, I can have 2 .pyc files.

However, `main.pyc` cannot be run if there is `no module named other`, which is the error I got from the terminal.

The idea is to compile the entire project from `.py` to `.pyc` so that people can run them without sharing the source code.

**So, how to run this `main.pyc` which imports other libraries, while not sharing the source code?**

Comment: have you tried execute other.pyc directly?

Comment: In fact, I tried. But do you think anything gonna happen if there is no function call in that .pyc file? Please take a look at other.py file above. Even if it converts to .pyc, there is still no function call inside of it. @georgexsh

Comment: this works for me, what is your environment?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu LTS with python3. Let me rephrase. I can successfully run other.pyc but nothing will happen since there is no function call inside of it. My goal is to run main.pyc file, which contains function calls from other files. Can you do that? @georgexsh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asked a machine learning group. Here is what I found.
As long as, `main.py` and `other.py` are compiled to `main.pyc` and `other.pyc`, I can run it by `python3 main.pyc`.

Before this, my python automatically converts `other.py` to `other.cpython-35.pyc`. In this case, `main.pyc` cannot `import other` since there is no `other` in the folder (it's called `other.cpython-35` now).

Thus, make sure `.pyc` file have the same name as `.py`, and then you can run any of them and python will include `.pyc` file for you when you execute the command.

Answer (score 7):

This can also be achieved by this command:

`python -m compileall -b .`

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

Python will ignore `pyc` files when a source file exists next to it. So after generating `main.pyc` and `other.pyc`, ensure that the source files `main.py` and `other.py` are moved out of the directory.

To be able to use `pyc` instead of `py` files.

- The compiled `pyc` files should be in the same folder as the source files
- The filename of the `pyc` should be the same as the source file
- The source `py` files should no longer exist next to the `pyc`

### Long answer

Python execution compiles source `py` files to compiled `pyc` files, even when not explicitly requested.

- Legacy Python would create the `pyc` files in the same directory as the source `py` files and with the same name.
- Newer versions create the `pyc` in a folder called `__pycache__` and the filename would include a "magic string" based on the Python version. E.g. `foo.cpython-37.pyc`.

So in newer versions of Python,

- the `pyc` have to be renamed to remove the magic number, `foo.cython-37.pyc` to `foo.pyc`
- the `pyc` files have to be moved from `__pycache__` folder to the parent source folder

The above can be achieved using the `compileall` module which should exist by default in Python installations.

`python -m compileall -b .`

The `-b` flag writes the byte-code files to their legacy locations and names, which may overwrite byte-code files created by another version of Python. The default is to write files to their PEP 3147 locations and names, which allows byte-code files from multiple versions of Python to coexist.

### References

[PEP 3147 – PYC Repository Directories](https://peps.python.org/pep-3147/) provides insight into the `py` and `pyc` files.

Here are a few relevant sections.

[Background](https://peps.python.org/pep-3147/#background)

> CPython compiles its source code into “byte code”, and for performance
> reasons, it caches this byte code on the file system whenever the
> source file has changes. This makes loading of Python modules much
> faster because the compilation phase can be bypassed.

[Proposal](https://peps.python.org/pep-3147/#proposal)

> Python’s import machinery is extended to write and search for byte
> code cache files in a single directory inside every Python package
> directory. This directory will be called **pycache**.
>
> Further, pyc file names will contain a magic string (called a “tag”)
> that differentiates the Python version they were compiled for. This
> allows multiple byte compiled cache files to co-exist for a single
> Python source file.

[Python behavior - Case 3: **pycache**/foo..pyc with no source](https://peps.python.org/pep-3147/#case-3-pycache-foo-magic-pyc-with-no-source)

> It’s possible that the foo.py file somehow got removed, while leaving
> the cached pyc file still on the file system. If the
> **pycache**/foo..pyc file exists, but the foo.py file used to create it does not, Python will raise an ImportError when asked to
> import foo. In other words, Python will not import a pyc file from the
> cache directory unless the source file exists.

[Python behavior - Case 4: legacy pyc files and source-less imports](https://peps.python.org/pep-3147/#case-4-legacy-pyc-files-and-source-less-imports)

> Python will ignore all legacy pyc files when a source file exists next
> to it. In other words, if a foo.pyc file exists next to the foo.py
> file, the pyc file will be ignored in all cases
>
> In order to continue to support source-less distributions though, if
> the source file is missing, Python will import a lone pyc file if it
> lives where the source file would have been.